# Magento1.9 - select products with similar price from product categories

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection

Given a `$product`, I need to get a random collection of 10 products belonging to the same categories of `$product` with a similar price - let's say +-15% the price of `$product`.

My idea is to get all product's `$categories`, then load a `$cat_products` collection for each category, then loop over `$cat_products` and check each `$cat_product` against my price condition and eventually add the `$cat_product` to an array if it matches. Then return the array.

```
$categoryIds = $product->getResource()->getCategoryIds($product);

foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
    $cat_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)

    foreach ($cat_products as $cat_product) {
        // check against my price conditions
    }
}
```

I didn't try it yet, but it should work. It looks extremely inefficient, though (also, I have a large catalog with many categories, and many categories - especially roots categories - are shared among products, so I would end up loading a few hundred thousands of products ...).

Any idea how can I get same result in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
$categoryIds = $product->getResource()->getCategoryIds($product);
$price = $product->getPrice();
$priceVriation = 15; // Percent Value for Variation

$minLimit = $price - ($price*$priceVriation)/100;
$maxLimit = $price + ($price*$priceVriation)/100;

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds))
->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addFinalPrice();
$collection->getSelect()->where("price_index.price <= $maxLimit AND price_index.price >= $minLimit")->group('e.entity_id')->limit(10)->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));

foreach($collection as $_product){
    echo $_product->getName()." with price = ". $_product->getPrice(). "<br>";
}
```

> Total Execution Time: 0.16790199279785 Seconds

**Output:**

```
My Product Price = 400.0000
Min Limit Price = 340
Max Limit Price = 460

Similar Price Products

Linen Blazer with price = 455.0000
Linen Blazer with price = 455.0000
Linen Blazer with price = 455.0000
Convertible Dress with price = 340.0000
Convertible Dress with price = 340.0000
Convertible Dress with price = 340.0000
Convertible Dress with price = 340.0000
Convertible Dress with price = 340.0000
Madison LX2200 with price = 425.0000
Linen Blazer with price = 455.0000
```

Comment: awesome! `+1` for the complete answer :) it works 'out of the box'. Just a question: how the 10 products are picked? first 10, randomly, ...?

Comment: Currently they are picked randomly. Because it will get products from all categories and then will get first 10 products from collection. But it won't change sequence if you refresh page.

Comment: Check updated code, now it will get 10 products randomly from collection and will change on each refresh.

Comment: How would you edit the `getSelect()` query in order to get products that belong to all the product's categories at the same time? I created an ad-hoc Q here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167561/magento1-9-get-product-with-specific-set-of-categoryids-filter-by-category-ar

Comment: Okay, I'll check and update you for the same

Answer (score 1):

You can use price range filter in product collection Like :

```
$categoryId = 2;
$cat_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
->addFieldToFilter('price', 
 array(array('from'=>'0','to'=>'50'))
 );
```

You can also calculate from and to price from current product price like

```
$fromPrice = $product->getPrice()-15
```