# Magento1.9 - get product with specific set of categoryIds (filter by category arrays)

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products

In my website there are `N` categories, let's say `1,2,3,4,5,6`.

Given `$categoryIds = array(1,2,3)` I need to get all the products that belong to **ALL** and **EXACTLY** the categories listed in `$categoryIds` (which is a subset of `N`).

e.g,

```
$productA->getResource()->getCategoryIds($productA) == (1,2,3)
$productB->getResource()->getCategoryIds($productB) == (2,4,5,6)
$productC->getResource()->getCategoryIds($productC) == (1,2,3,4)
$productD->getResource()->getCategoryIds($productD) == (1,2)
$productE->getResource()->getCategoryIds($productE) == (4,5,6)
```

Only **$productA** must be selected by my script.

How can I customize following code to get it?

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds))
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$collection->addFinalPrice();
$collection->getSelect()
        ->where("price_index.price <= $maxLimit AND price_index.price >= $minLimit")
        ->group('e.entity_id')
        ->limit(10)
        ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with below code.

```
$categoryIds = $product->getResource()->getCategoryIds($product);
$categoryCount = count($categoryIds);
$price = $product->getPrice();
$priceVriation = 15; // Percent Value for Variation

$minLimit = $price - ($price*$priceVriation)/100;
$maxLimit = $price + ($price*$priceVriation)/100;

$readAdapter = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$collection->addFinalPrice();

// Add total number of Category for a product as a new column.
$select = $readAdapter->select()
    ->from('catalog_category_product')
    ->columns(array('category_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*)'))
)->group('product_id');
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('category_count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('('.$select.')')),
    'e.entity_id = category_count.product_id',
    array('category_count.category_count')
);
// Ends

$collection->getSelect()
    ->where("price_index.price <= $maxLimit AND price_index.price >= $minLimit AND category_count.category_count = $categoryCount")
    ->group('entity_id')
    ->having('count(at_category_id.category_id) = ?', $categoryCount)
    ->limit(10)
    ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));

foreach($collection as $_product){
    echo $_product->getSku(). "<br>";
}
```

It will give you products which has exact same categories.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I still get pretty random - unexpected - results.. what do the `->having('count(category_id) = ?', $categoryCount)` bits do? I can't get the logic behind.. pls note that `array(1,2,3)` is a subset of the total category list.. so a product with `$categoryIds = array(1,2,4)` would still be considered in your script, right? I need to get all the product that belong EXACTLY to the categories 1,2,3

Comment: No, with above script subset will not be matched, if you want to match with `ANY` value, answer on your previous question was correct. If you want `ALL` categories to match, above should work for you.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain me well. I mean that in my website there are `N` categories, let's say 1,2,3,4,5,6. I need to get the product that belong only to `n` (which is a subset of `N`), let's say 1,2,3. Your script adds to the collection also product with `$categoryIds = array(2,3,6)`, since the only condition is that at least one category is in `n` and `count == count(n)`. Please correct me if I'm wrong, I really appreciate your time. Thanks

Comment: Can you add these details to question as its hard to understand from comment. If you will add example it will be great

Comment: I rephrased the original Q to be clearer

Comment: @davideghz, did you get it working?

Comment: Hi Jaimin, I think your solution works fine, but honestly didn't test it since I changed my approach; I now load the product collection in memory, I build an array with only the info that I need, and then I filter it. It's faster since I do not have to query the DB several time